# How to store x,y graphs: (a) Using x,y columns for each point, or (b) to store the set of points as comma separated strings?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2016

We are designing a database to store the X,Y graph data of electronic devices apart from other entities.

### Business domain description

- We have a collection of objects A, each object A has a collection of objects B.
- Each object B has a collection of X,Y points forming a graph.

For example:

- Object A has a collection of ~30,000 to 50,000 object B instances.
- Each object B instance has X,Y graph data of about 200 to 250 points of double values.

Expected data size:

- ~ 100,000 A instances
- ~ 50,000 B Instances in each A
- ~ 200 graph points

Number of rows:

- 100,000 * 50,000 * 200 = 1,000,000,000,000 = 1 trillion.

**Requirements**

- The users are interested in fetching the entire data set of an object B instance, not of a single point.
- The users are interested in getting the X,Y points of all the B object instances for a given object instance A.
- **Users rarely fetch, probably like one or two queries in a day for a given object instance of A.**

### Considerations

**Design 1**

Standard-approach design in the simpler form to design the database to retain point data:

[image]

- **Pros**: The data is stored "directly" so retrieval doesn't need any conversion.
- **Cons**: The table ends up with trillion of rows, we need to do table partition to get quicker access of data.

**Design 2**

To store as comma separated values:

[image]

- **Pros**: Data table size is confined to the instance counts of Object B.
- **Cons**: Involves using string split to convert the string to rows or to give the data in the comma separated format to the user.

Answer (score 1):

There's a third option: store column 2 and 3 together, so like

```
X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3
```

If you're **absolutely sure** you never need to sort or filter on these coordinates, and rely on application logic to create, update and process them, it's fine to store them as a 'blob' in a single column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, isn't going to be more work when we retrieve the data as we need to give the end user with two rows one for X values and another row for y values corresponding to the x values

Comment: As an end user, I'd rather get a list of tuples; if they'd import it into Excel, they need two *columns* (not two rows) anyway. But the performance difference is probably negligible.